# Python Pandas Conversion of days

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I am trying to change string to a datetime64[ns] format in format days.month.year, but I get this error:

ValueError: time data '01.02.2016' does not match format '%dd.%mm.%YYYY' (match)

```
df['Start Date 2']= pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'], format = "%dd.%mm.%YYYY")
```

Or Can I somehow modify this code? To have desired output in format of days.month.year?

```
df['Start Date 1']=df['Start Date'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

This is how the input values look like: `'01.02.2016'` it is in format days.months.years

I want the output look like this but being a datetime64[ns] format

Comment: Have you tried a format of `'%d.%m.%Y'` ? You're asking for the day to be followed by the letter `d`, the month to be a month followed by the letter m, and the year to be a four digit year followed by 3 `Y`s...

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct format:

```
df['Start Date 2']= pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'], format = '%d.%m.%Y')
```